# Flask-security Flask-login | login as a user before first request

Tags: python, flask-login, flask-security

I am trying to login as a user as soon as I start the server. I am using `flask-security` which uses `flask-login` to handle users log in and out.
I attempted this:
**Code:**

```
@app.before_first_request
   def login_user():
       user_datastore.create_user(email='admin', password='admin')
       login_user("admin","admin")
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call your login_user function inside login_user().

Try:

```
from flask_security.utils import login_user
@app.before_first_request
def login_admin()
    admin = user_datastore.create_user(email='admin', password='admin')
    login_user(admin)
```

From flask-security docs:

http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security-Fork/api.html?#utils